# Reset Form (Reactive Forms)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ng-template [ngIf]="userIsAuthenticated">
    <form [formGroup]='form' name="test">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="header" placeholder="Post Header" formControlName="header">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Post Message" formControlName="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="file1" ng-model="test1" (change)="onFilePicked($event)">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="postbtn" type="button" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="onSavePost()">{{ btnText }}</button>
    </form>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

There is more to it but I use this to reset the form in the TS file:

`this.form.reset();`

This resets everything apart from the file.

I created this in the mean time to remove the file:

`<button ng-click="angular.copy(file1)" #filePicker id="file2" type="reset">Remove files</button>` But using this didnt seem like good practice.

I have also tried this in the ts file. 
`this.form.value.file.nativeElement.value = '';`

This seems to reload the page, which is not good.

Any advice would be great *PLEASE* only contributional comments.

Comment: Did you try, `this.form.value.file.nativeElement.reset()`, or maybe even `this.form.reset()`

Comment: ... side comment: `ng-model` and `ng-click` is AngularJS...

Comment: this.form.nativeElement.reset()
Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, these have all been tried, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by binding your input to avalie model with

```
<input ng-model="test1"> --> <input [(ngModel)]="test1" #fileInput>
```

And to reset it, declare it as a view child, then reset it like this

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

resetForm() {
  this.form.reset();
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.value = undefined;
}
```

Comment: It's telling me, I cant bind ng-Model because it is not known as a property of input.

Comment: You need to import `FormModule`. But you dont really need it, simply remove `ng-model` from your input (I was telling you that because your current `ng-model` syntax does nothing)

Comment: Okay, thanks that's changed now, but there seem to be a few errors, with the element ref. View Child got imported etc but still not happy with the element ref.

Comment: Did you import ElementRef too ?

Comment: Yeah, that's been imported. `@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;` is shouting that a Declaration expected. From the things you gave me was I supposed to rename any of them?

Comment: You need to declare this as a member of your class. Did you do that ? it would be like `export class XXXComponent implements OnInit { @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174346/discussion-between-andrew-and-trichetriche).